# Target multiple .Net framework in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I got a some projects that need to be built for both .Net 3.5 and .Net 4 in VS2010.

The projects got different configurations and I edited the project file to include

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

or

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

under each configuration.

This has worked fine in C# projects for a long time but now I need to do the same for a VB.Net project.

The strange thing is in VB.Net where the resulting v3.5 assembly got references to both mscorlib 2.0 **and mscorlib 4.0**

My guess is the mscorlib 4.0 reference comes from the Microsoft.VisualBasic reference.

So my question is how I can get VS2010 to load the .Net 3.5 version of Microsoft.VisualBasic (8.0.0.0) in one project configuration and the .Net 4 version (10.0.0.0) in another?

Some background on why I need to do this: The project work as plugins in another application. The application can run in CLR4 or CLR2 (older versions) but the plugin need to work with both. If I target .Net 3.5 it will load fine in both CLR2 and CLR4 but the debugger in VS2010 will not work in CLR4. i.e. I need to target .Net 4 for the debug version and .Net 3.5 for the release version.

Comment: Best writeup I've seen : http://alandean.blogspot.com/2011/02/framework-version-targeting-with.html  Not sure if it translates to vb.net